# How to move worksheets to a new workbook vba

Tags: vba, excel

How do I move worksheets into the new workbook based on specific criteria?

If worksheets cell H1 (or cells(1,8)) contains "PI Fin Ops" I need the worksheets to be moved to a new workbook.

My guess is below but it doesnt work. Any help is much appreciated!

```
Sub NewWb()

    For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Cells(1, 8).Value = "PI Fin Ops" Then
            Worksheet.Move After:=Workbooks.Add
        End If
    Next Worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out from the last question you asked?  It seems similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107016/how-do-i-select-multiple-worksheets-to-move-based-on-cell-content If the answers to your last question didn't help you, no worries; just leave a note in the comments explaining why.  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107016/how-do-i-select-multiple-worksheets-to-move-based-on-cell-content

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Sub NewWb()

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add

    For Each ws In wb1.Sheets
        If ws.Cells(1, 8).Value = "PI Fin Ops" Then
            ws.Move After:=wb2.Sheets(wb2.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Some of your mistakes :

1. You were adding a new workbook everytime you wanted to move the sheet
2. You were not moving the sheet to the right place (you must move before or after a worksheet (*not a workbook*))
3. Inside your loop, you were always referring to the same 'worksheet' (the *active* one)

I think using the word "Worksheet" as a variable name is proscribed.

Comment: Hi Bernard. I am getting a runtime error 13 type mismatch with a call out of this line: If Worksheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = "PI Fin Ops" Then

Answer (score 1):

this function will loop through the worksheets and add them to a new workbook then returns the workbook object.

```
Function NewWb() As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Cells(1, 8).Value = "PI Fin Ops" Then
        ws.Move After:=wb.Sheets(1)
    End If
Next ws

Set NewWb = wb
End Function
```